# Google play asking Privacy policy

Tags: android, google-play

I am uploading an app. I am collecting username and email id of the registered user in Firebase. But while uploading my app, the store listing column specifies your apk requires `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`, but I am not using that permission in my Manifest. How should I resolve this?

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html

Answer (score 0):

you have to link a privacy policy page of you website when you upload app to google store.

Comment: I dont have a website and i dont know how to create a policy page and url

Comment: But it's compulsory to put privacy policy page brother if you do not do this then you can not upload apk to store.

Comment: Can you tell me how to create it free of cost?

Comment: http://www.wix.com/html5en/hiker-create?experiment_id=%2Bfree%20%2Bweb%20%2Bmake%5Eb%5E48482440900%5E1t1&gclid=CjwKCAjwoNrMBRB4EiwA_ODYv7zCLkDCa5-Ngk4PbTg7RGpnuLoA0kFroLOr4E0w7SZk6PhHvzPUtxoCLqEQAvD_BwE&utm_campaign=219565660%5E10611550900&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google  GO THROUGH THIS LINK YOU WILL GET TO KNOW ABOUT IT

Comment: how to create privacy policy url?